# Funny characters in MySQL database after import

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I exported and then imported a wordpress mysql database from one server to another.

On the new server, a lot of the apostrophes have turned to question mark symbols ?.  When I look at the data in the database itself, the apostrophes are normal like this ' so what would be causing those characters to look messed up?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the collation on both databases to see if they match? Also, you need to check that your escape characters are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` on both servers. The difference might be related to the CHARSET.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the corresponding collation in the select, for example

SELECT k
FROM t1
ORDER BY k COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;

One common collation name could be SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1254_CS_AS

here is a list of collation names:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx